# Windows equivalent of Unix last

Tags: windows-10

Unix's `last` command gives a list of logging-in and logging-out events.
I'm looking for something which would give me the same information for Windows-10, preferably something which can generate a text file with the information, a Windows API would be the next best thing, a program which would allow me to look at the information without a way to further process it elsewhere would also work but be inconvenient.

I've administrator access if this is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to WIN10 too, but I think so. In Windows 7 you can run `eventvwr.msc` and under `windows logs/security` you find login / logout logs. They can be exported in different formats from this program.

Comment: Works in W10 too. Eventlog can also be queried via API calls. Easiest is to use Powershell's Get-EventLog command: The MSDN page on that has a lot of good examples.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, there is a lot of events in these log, filtering for 4647 and 4648 gave me those I was looking for.